# Issue with pandas.DataFrame.to_csv ('tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have imported a csv file and manipulated the data with pandas.
I would now like to write out the df to a csv, but am receiving error:
'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

I have tried the following:

```
   df = pd.read_csv(destintation_path + '/' + filename),
   index_col=False,
   usecols=[1,2,3], 
   parse_dates=[0],
   header=0,
   names=["lineItem_referenceNo", "lineItem_tenantId", "lineItem_intervalUsageStart"]
   logging.info(df)

   export_csv = df.to_csv(destintation_path + '/' + filename, header=True)
```

The returned message is:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: You closed your parentheses too soon... Move the end parenthesis after `names=[...]`

Comment: @PierreV. you should probably post this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are closing you parenthesis too early. Try this corrected line:

```
df = pd.read_csv(destintation_path + '/' + filename,
   index_col=False,
   usecols=[1,2,3], 
   parse_dates=[0],
   header=0,
   names=["lineItem_referenceNo", "lineItem_tenantId", "lineItem_intervalUsageStart"])
logging.info(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use

`df.to_csv("filename.csv" )`

and this works fine for me. It outputs the csv to the same directory of my notebook.